# Set Konva transform controls to the top of the canvas

Tags: javascript, konvajs, react-konva

I'm trying to transform an image that sits behind another layer holding a png ( the template ). I want to transform the image below this layer but keep it where it is so the above layer stays as the template.

Is it possible to show the transform controls at the top above everything?

```
<Stage width={480} height={620} onMouseDown={this.handleStageMouseDown}>
    {this.props.file ? (
      <Layer>
        <Uploaded file={this.props.file} />

        <TransformerComponent
          selectedShapeName={this.state.selectedShapeName}
        />
      </Layer>
    ) : null}
    <Layer listening={false}>
      <Overlay />
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
```

[image: SHows how the png overlays the controls and the transformable image underneath]

Comment: Maybe set the template layer.listening attr to false so that it does not capture the mouse events ?

Comment: Yeah that's working ok with the prop `listening={false}`, but no way to bring the controls above that layer?

Comment: Your description is useful but could you maybe add a screen grab of what you see. I want t visualise the template and understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat sure, added one in to see if it helps to understand the issue.

Comment: I recommend that you create a duplicate of the image that is being transformed in the bottom layer, make it semi-transparent so the user can see the template,  and place it on top of the template layer whilst in transform mode. Hide the one in the bottom layer while transforming. Let the user do their transforming and on completion hide the dummy image, using its position & size for the image in the bottom layer and revealing it. Your only issue then is triggering the show & hide of the dummy image.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat thanks for your help on this. I actually implemented this solution as I preferred it. But the client wanted something closer to the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the structure of your nodes. Just show transformer on top of all other shapes. If you need to disable events for overlayer, you can use `listening={false}`.

```
<Stage width={480} height={620} onMouseDown={this.handleStageMouseDown}>
  <Layer>
    {this.props.file &&
        <Uploaded file={this.props.file} />
    }
    {/* use listening={false} for image in overlay */}
    <Overlay/>
    <TransformerComponent
         selectedShapeName={this.state.selectedShapeName}
     />
</Stage>
```

Comment: Just an additional note - I concur with your answer, but I think the OP uses a template like a picture frame that the user is targeting with the image, and the transformer is to be used to size and position the image so that it is placed pleasingly within the frame of the template layer. This is why I suggested that the transformer image needs to be made semi-transparent.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. Thanks for all your work on Konva

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's looking for a solution using hooks, I found that if you have a ref for the Transformer, you can easily call the `zIndex()` method with an arbitrarily high number when your shape is selected, then redraw it to be safe (it might work without this part)

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSelected) {
    trRef.current.zIndex(10000);
    trRef.current.getLayer().batchDraw();
  }
}, [isSelected]);
```

This seems to render the Transformer above everything else on the canvas, even if the shape itself is obscured.